# Charger specification of 3000mah battery

Tags: battery-charging, batteries

I am planning on making a USB charger for my Tablet whose battery is of 3000mah. What should be the output current and voltage required for the charger? Is there anything else other than the output current and voltage that I should consider?
I am planning to make the charger using dry cell/9V battery so that I can recharge the tablet while travelling using the power of the dry cell/battery.
The AC adapter for recharging my tablet says: Output: 5V====1.5A But since I am able to recharge the Tablet by simply plugging into my PCs USB port(output of which I believe is 5V, 500-900mah) 1.5A is not necessary right?

Comment: Have a read of http://delicious.com/redirect?url=http%3A//www.arcfn.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html but especially the footnotes, as they describe the USB charger signalling and link to some reference designs.

Comment: The power you can get out of a typical 9v battery will not be enough to make any noticable difference in battery life on a tablet.

Comment: What if I use 9V Lithium battery?(output current 1200mah). Will there be any different if I use some AAA batteries in series? I believe AAA batteries have more power output than the rest.

Comment: 1200mah is a capacity not a current, and it's a capacity of less than half the tablet battery. Any solution involving dry cells isn't going to give you more than a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that claims to be a "USB" charger needs to follow the USB spec for voltage, which is nominal 5 V.  Of course there is some slop.  If I remember right for a regular USB device which can draw up to 500 mA, the range is something like 4.3 to 5.2 at the device.  Check the USB spec for details.

USB chargers can supply more power, and the device signals that by messing with the data lines in a particular way, like shorting them to ground if I remember right.  I'm not sure, so you need to check the spec yourself.  In that case higher currents are envolved, so there is probably a different valid voltage range that the device has to deal with, and of course a narrower range that the charger has to supply.  I don't know the exact ranges, but basically the charger needs to supply "5 volts".  9 volts would be bad and could easily damage devices expecting about 5 V.

Comment: So does it mean that whatever the current output of the charger is, it doesn't matter and all I have to make sure is that the output voltage is 5V. I am not sure about the batteries other spec than 3000mah(it is not provided by the manufacturers) but my AC adapter says:
Output: 5V====1.5A
But since I am able to recharge the Tablet by simply plugging into my PCs USB port(output of which I believe is 5V, 500-900mah) 1.5A is not necessary right?

Comment: @Harik: Basically you need to provide a stiff 5 V supply somehow.  It can be capable of more current, but should be able to supply at least 1.5A in this case.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - as he is having success with a port that he says is not capable of 1.5A (and it may or may not be) then less than 1.5A may be OK. Of course, 1.5A capability is best if that's the charger spec.

Comment: @Harik: Russell makes a good point.  If it's working with a plain PC USB port, then *maybe* your charger doesn't need to be capable of 1.5 A.  It is possible that your device detects a "real" USB port and only draws 500 mA after negotiation, but it probably just draws what it wants.  That may be more than 500 mA and your PC may be letting it, so we don't really know how little you can get away with.  1.5A is safe, but lower is probably OK.